# delete value from table mssql where value is string and like string

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains databases.

I use a sql job to fill this table.
one of the columns in the table looks like this:

```
database_name  (column name*) 
master
tempdb
model
database1
database2
testdatabase1
testdatabase2
```

Next step in the job is to delete the system databases, I use the following code for this:

```
delete from table_name
where column_name in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
```

Now what I want is, to also delete all databases that containt TEST in their name. I tried something like this, but its not working.

```
delete from table_name
where column_name in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','%test%')
```

Also tried:

```
delete from table_name
where column_name in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
and like ('%test%')
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from table_name
where column_name in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
or column_name like '%test%'
```

use the above query.

Comment: Works, thanks. Do you know how I would use it for multiple excluded values? example %test% and %production%

Comment: delete from table_name
where column_name in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
or column_name like '%test%' or column_name like '%production%'

Comment: add another condition using 'or'